# onBlur Event Function Fires on Pageload in Vanila Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, blur, onblur

I have a basic validation function and a `addEventListener` to attach to a `select` element. Now, not only doesn't the function fire when during the event, but it fires on `pageload`. Can you  please help me figure out why?

The **element** is:

```
<select name="VisitSchedLocation" id="VisitSchedLocation" size="1">
  <option value="">Choose a location for this visit</option>
  <option value="1">Location 1</option>
  ...
</select>
```

The `addEventListener` is:

```
document.getElementById('VisitSchedLocation').addEventListener('blur', validateVisitSchedLocation());
```

And, finally, the **function**:

```
function validateVisitSchedLocation() {
  if (VisitSchedLocation.options[VisitSchedLocation.selectedIndex].value == '') {
    alert('Location must be selected!');
    return false;
  };
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7p4m2/)

You are calling/invoking the function rather than attaching it to event:

```
document.getElementById('VisitSchedLocation').addEventListener('blur', validateVisitSchedLocation());
```

Instead do this (***No parentheses***):

```
document.getElementById('VisitSchedLocation').addEventListener('blur', validateVisitSchedLocation);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gurpreet Singh. That stopped the firing on pageload, but it still doesn't fire on blur. I even changed the code from **blur** to **onblur** to no avail.

Comment: @ShulemJ, blur is fine. The demo I have provided works just fine. Note blur doesn't work on change, it only works when element loses focus. You can try 'change' instead.

Comment: Thanks again. I must have had a typo, because I pasted your code over mine and it works now. Thanks for everything.